# Word Game Solver

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to play word games that give you a set of letters and you get points for the more words you can make out of those letters. I have some code that works, but it's pretty slow. I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to speed it up or if this is even the right place for this.

Here's the code

```
import itertools
import os
import urllib.request
import sys

# PREWORK
DICTIONARY = os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'words.txt')
dictionary = []
with open(DICTIONARY) as f:
    [dictionary.append(word.strip().lower()) for word in f.read().split()]


def get_possible_dict_words(draw):
    """Get all possible words from a draw (list of letters) which are
       valid dictionary words. Use _get_permutations_draw and provided
       dictionary"""
    combinations = _get_permutations_draw(draw)
    listOfPossibleWords = []
    try:
        while True:
            combination = next(combinations)
            combination = ''.join(combination)
            if combination in listOfPossibleWords:
                continue
            if combination in dictionary:
                listOfPossibleWords.append(combination)
    except StopIteration:
        if listOfPossibleWords:
            return listOfPossibleWords
        else:
            print("There are no combinations made with those letters.")


def _get_permutations_draw(draw):
    """Helper to get all permutations of a draw (list of letters), hint:
       use itertools.permutations (order of letters matters)"""
    for _ in range(1, len(draw) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.permutations(draw, _):
            yield(subset)


def main():
    draw = input("Please enter each letter seperated by spaces: ").split(" ")
    print(get_possible_dict_words(draw))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

[@alecxe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/24208/alecxe) has the right idea, but there is more to improve

## Review

- `sys.path[0]` is unnecessary

  The default of `open(filename)` will look in the in the current directory, so there is no need to convert it to a full path beforehand
- `dictionary` should also be a CONSTANT

  Since dictionary is a global constant it should be written in `ALL_CAPS`

  Secondly this variable is oddly named, `dictionary` is a datatype (hashmap) in python.
- Change the data type of `dictionary`

  @alecxe mentioned this as well, but a `set` will give O(0) lookup, instead of O(n), we can make the dictionary of words a set for faster lookup times
- `_` variables are used for variables you don't use later on.

  You do use the variable so rename it.

## Code

```
from itertools import permutations

WORD_FILE = 'words.txt'

def read_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return {word.strip().lower() for word in f.readlines()}

def get_possible_words(target, word_set):
    used_words = set()
    for comb in get_permutations(target):
        if comb in word_set:
            used_words.add(comb)
    return used_words or "There are no combinations made with those letters."

def get_permutations(target):
    for i in range(1, len(target) + 1):
        for subset in permutations(target, i):
            yield(''.join(subset))

def main():
    target = input("Please enter each letter seperated by spaces: ").split()
    print(get_possible_words(target, read_words(WORD_FILE)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You may want to clarify your sentence about `_`: It's *by convention* that it's used for temporary variables, but there's nothing inherently special about an underscore. It's a variable like any other. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/8117067) may be a useful link to add to your answer.

Comment: @Graham I should've made it more clear it is convention to use `_` for throwaway variables. Thnx for the link, will edit when I have a little more time

Answer (score 2):

My idea when it comes to optimizing code is to check the runtime with a profiler. Python has a useful module called cProfile with which you can easily track how long the individual function calls take.
With the main call wrapped in to

```
import cProfile
...
cProfile.run('main()')
```

I get the following result

```
Please enter each letter seperated by spaces: t e s t d a r r e
['a', 'at', 'as', 'ad', 'art', 'test', 'dear', 'date', 'dare', 'desert', 'arrest']
         4932040 function calls in 20.747 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   20.747   20.747 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:318(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:330(getstate)
   986409    0.234    0.000    0.234    0.000 word_game.py:14(_in_list_of_possibles)
   986379   14.626    0.000   14.626    0.000 word_game.py:21(_in_dictionary)
        1    0.800    0.800   16.245   16.245 word_game.py:28(get_possible_dict_words)
   986410    0.205    0.000    0.205    0.000 word_game.py:49(_get_permutations_draw)
        1    0.000    0.000   20.747   20.747 word_game.py:57(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
        1    0.000    0.000   20.747   20.747 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    4.501    4.501    4.501    4.501 {built-in method builtins.input}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
   986410    0.205    0.000    0.411    0.000 {built-in method builtins.next}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   986409    0.175    0.000    0.175    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
```

I added two functions

```
def _in_list_of_possibles(combi, list_of_possibles):
    if combi in list_of_possibles:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def _in_dictionary(combi, dictionary):
    if combi in dictionary:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

in order to get a better understanding of how long these steps take.
And with this we can see that the lookup of the combination in the dictionary is the culprit whereas the look up in the newly composed list of possibles doesn't really affect performance.

<strike>My idea of performance increase would go into the direction of multi threading the lookup in the dictionary.</strike>

Following the idea of [@ludisposed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/140549/ludisposed): Converting the dictionary into a set increases performance quite significantly.

Comment: While I agree with parts of your answer, (use cprofile to check where the bottlenecks are) I don't agree with your last point. Why use multi threading, if you could make the `dictionary` variable a `set` essentially giving O(0) lookup.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. 
According to the Zen of python: Simple is better than complex.

Comment: I apologize for that, I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Couple straightforward things that should provide performance and memory usage improvements:

- `if combination in listOfPossibleWords:` if `listOfPossibleWords` is a list is a *slow full-scan operation* with \$O(n)\$ complexity. By switching to a set, you would get constant time lookups

  ```
  possible_words = set([])
  try:
      while True:
          combination = next(combinations)
          combination = ''.join(combination)
          if combination in possible_words:
              continue
          if combination in dictionary:
              possible_words.add(combination)
      # ...
  ```

  FYI, here is a handy complexity table for Python date structures: [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)
- when you are reading the file, the `f.read()` would read the whole contents of the file into memory. You could iterate over the file line by line in a "lazy" manner instead:

  ```
  with open(DICTIONARY) as f:
      dictionary = [word.strip().lower() for word in f]
  ```

  Note that I've also updated it to be a proper pythonic list comprehension.